# Using System.IO on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, system.io.file

I would like to create a simple file using `System.IO` when clicking on a button. My code does in fact generate the file but it creates the file every time the browser reloads rather than only generating on button click. Below is my code. Can anyone help and see if they can figure out why this fires on page load?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ColorPicker
{
    public partial class ColorPicker : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Empty for now
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            SetEventHandlers();
        }

        private void GenerateSassFile()
        {
            var ColorInputVal = ColorInput;
            ColorInputVal.Attributes.Add("class", "form-control");
            ColorInputVal.Attributes.Add("value", "#000");

            var ColorInputH = this.ColorInputH.Value = "red";

            var RenderStyleBtn = RenderStyle;
            RenderStyleBtn.Text = "Render!";

            string path = @"c:\ColorPicker\Scss\_vars.scss";
            // Create a file to write to.
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("$primary: " + ColorInputH + " !important;");
            }

            // Open the file to read from.
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
            {
                string s;
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
        }


        private void RenderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GenerateSassFile();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Button clicked");
        }

        private void SetEventHandlers()
        {
            RenderStyle.Click += RenderButton_Click;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you on browser reload transmit  post data again? If postdata contains the viewstate, it has the info of eventual events happened for launching  that post, over the data contained in the form posted... so if you retransmit that after the Renderstyle click, the page class revisit the viewstate info and finds again the click event of your RenderStyle button, launching the click delegate again

Comment: Don't assign events handlers manually. For your button, use the ASPX markup to assign the handler.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line, I assume RenderStyle is different of RenderButton, and you are firing RenderButton everytime you fire RenderStyle.

```
RenderStyle.Click += RenderButton_Click;
```

So it is "GenerateSassFile" everytime you press RenderStyle button.